# Airflow initdb fails due to SyntaxError on importing AsyncRetrying

Tags: installation, airflow, python-3.7

I am new to Airflow. I install it by `pip install apache-airflow`. When I run command `airflow initdb` in terminal then I am getting the error below. Where did I go wrong during install, and how can I fix this issue?

```
aamir@aamir-Inspiron-3542:~$ airflow initdb
[2019-03-30 18:32:27,309] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
DB: sqlite:////home/aamir/airflow/airflow.db
[2019-03-30 18:32:31,790] {db.py:338} INFO - Creating tables
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
ERROR [airflow.models.DagBag] Failed to import: /home/aamir/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/example_dags/example_http_operator.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aamir/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 374, in process_file
    m = imp.load_source(mod_name, filepath)
  File "/home/aamir/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/aamir/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/example_dags/example_http_operator.py", line 27, in <module>
    from airflow.operators.http_operator import SimpleHttpOperator
  File "/home/aamir/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/http_operator.py", line 21, in <module>
    from airflow.hooks.http_hook import HttpHook
  File "/home/aamir/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/hooks/http_hook.py", line 23, in <module>
    import tenacity
  File "/home/aamir/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 352
    from tenacity.async import AsyncRetrying
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Done.
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3.7, `async` is a reserved keyword, which means it cannot be used in module and variable names. This was valid in prior Python versions, but starting from 3.7, a `SyntaxError` is raised.

In your case, Airflow comes pre-installed with example DAGs, which were parsed when you ran `airflow initdb`. Some of those DAGs make use of the `SimpleHttpOperator` which depends on [`http_hook.py`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/hooks/http_hook.py#L23). That hook furthermore depends on the `tenacity` library, which tries to import an `async` module as part of initialization:

```
 from tenacity.async import AsyncRetrying
```

To fix this, wait for/install Airflow v1.10.3 which updates Tenacity (see [AIRFLOW-2876](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-2876)). Alternatively, you can downgrade your Python version. You can see that the import fails using 3.7.3:

```
$ docker run --rm -it python:3.7
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 23:40:30)

>>> from tenacity.async import AsyncRetrying
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    from tenacity.async import AsyncRetrying
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But it works fine in version 3.6.8:

```
$ docker run --rm -it python:3.6
Python 3.6.8 (default, Feb  6 2019, 12:07:20)

>>> from tenacity.async import AsyncRetrying
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tenacity'
```

Comment: I think this had [already been patched](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-2716) in `v1.10.x`; **@Aamir Siddiqui** which version of `Airflow` are you using?

Comment: @y2k-shubham this is patched by AIRFLOW-2876, which is making its way into `v1.10.3`. I'll update the answer to include.

Comment: i think this was [added in `v1.10.0` itself](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/CHANGELOG.txt#L418) and `Python 3.7.2` seems to [play nicely](https://imgur.com/a/HyqzUWj) with me for `Airflow v1.10.2`

Comment: I don't believe so - see [here](https://gist.github.com/hexacyanide/44342125b0b3fe3c119081b6d2db8102#file-initdb-log-L49). You can test this in your Python env with `import tenacity`.